# Toolbar show/hide instead of scrolling up/down while scrolling in recyclerview

Tags: android, toolbar

I want to make my app do something like google + ,google play music

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2JyRFpa0Xo

Currently I use the coordinator layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

But the problem is that my toolbar only scrolls along with the layout, just like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFNQ2mp7Lpg

How can I fix this with the coordinator layout?

Comment: Try to change scroll flags to `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`

Comment: @Piyush https://gist.github.com/BoldijarPaul/8adcdd9380ccb88deb2933ca45cf228b , now the only way to see the toolbar is to scroll to the top of the list..otherwise toolbar won't show up, and it's also scrolling on the same layout, the toolbar isn't showing on on top of the layout as on the google music app..